# Structuring dynamic information with classes, C#

Tags: c#

I am not well versed in object oriented programing. I am working in C# here. I am learning this whole thing with a simple thermostat that will have a GUI. My question relates to how I would best go about structuring my schedule for the thermostat. I am thinking some sort of class, but there is multilevel hierarchy for the class (right terms?).

Level 1 - Mode
Heating or Cooling Mode

Level 2 - Day of Week
Day of Week Differentiation

Level 3 - Time block
Wake, Leave, Return, and Sleep

So, depending on if we are heating or cooling, we have a different schedule. Also, day of week can have unique time blocks. Finally, each time block can have a unique temperature.

The values are stored until the user changes the schedule.

Coming from a MCU background, I'm thinking: just assign a variable or array to cover each case, and manually loop through it all. This is tedious as even in the simplest case of weekday/weekend, same start/stop each day we have 16 variants.

Is there a better way?

Something like

```
Console.WriteLine(Heating.Monday.Wake.Time);
Console.WriteLine(Heating.Monday.Wake.Setpoint);
//Output:
//14:00
//72
```

Comment: Not sure what's the `Level` is for, I don't see the value of it. Based on the info you given, I would have an `interface` named like `IThermostatMode` with all it's common properties and method that heating and cooling would have from there you would have `Heating` and `Cooling` implement that `interface`. This is as far as I will go, as this is the the place to help you learn programming.

Comment: Probably a marginally better fit on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ but I'd say the question needs work regardless.

Comment: @AustinFrench when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)